# Symmetric Binary relations on N equinumerous to 2^N

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am attempting to establish that the set of all symmetric binary relations on N (a set R is symmetric if (a, b) is in R implies (b, a) is in R) is equinumerous to 2^N and am having some difficulty.

My attempt was to define a bijection as follows: let B be the set of all symmetric binary relations on N. Define f:B->2^n as A in B is mapped to g(A) where g(A) : NxN->{0,1} as (a, b) ={0 if (a, b) is not in A. 1 if (a, b) is in A. 
Unfortunately I don't think this is a bijection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Clearly there cannot be *more* than $2^\Bbb N$ symmetric relations; bound it from below by showing that for every $A\subseteq\Bbb N$, $R_A=A\times A$ is a symmetric relation on $\Bbb N$. Conclude that there are at least $2^\Bbb N$ symmetric relations, and use the Cantor-Bernstein theorem.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it intuitively, but I can't seem to figure out an injection either direction

Comment: Which other direction? The "clearly" part?

Comment: Yes, I understand why it's true, as 2^n subsets but I can't get an injection that works

Comment: **HINT:** There is a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb{N\times N}$.

Comment: Okay, so since each symmetric binary relation is contained in NxN, there is the inclusion map, so injective, then we want to map N to some binary string, so take a function from 2^N, am I on the right track?

Comment: Given any subset of $\Bbb{N\times N}$, using a fixed bijection as above, consider the function which gives $1$ to the values which encode a pair from that subset and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Oh okay perfect that makes sense! Sorry to keep bugging you, I'm a bit lost on the other direction as well. My thoughts are to map a string S in 2^N into (n, n) for if there is a 1 in the nth position in S, but I don't know what to do for the 0 case

Comment: Well, do the simpler thing: Prove that $2^{\Bbb N}$ and $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ have the same cardinality. So now we have that $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ and $\mathcal P(\Bbb{N\times N})$ have the same cardinality. Working with subsets is slightly easier in this case.

Comment: Okay, yes that definitely does make it easier to think about. I'm still not seeing it though, I tried mapping it to B by inserting (a, b) and (b, a) into some symmetric set for every (a, b) in some subset of the power set, but this isn't injective

Comment: Just map $A$ to $A\times A$. It's not hard to prove that this is in injective function from $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ to $\mathcal P(\Bbb{N\times N})$.